# jquery on button click show tooltip above button

Tags: jquery, html

I need to show div above button on button click with jquery.

```
$("#but button").click(function(){
    $("#mydiv").css("display","block");
    });

<div id="but"><button type="button">Show Div!</button></div>
<div id="mydiv" style="display: none;">The div must be above button</div>
```

**UPDATE**

I need to make as a tooltip above the button.

Comment: put the div above the button then!! O.o

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recommend taking an hour to read through the [jQuery API documentation](http://api.jquery.com). It literally only takes that long, but pays off enormously.

**Update**

Your edit about making it a tooltip completely changes the question. You'd probably want to position the div using `position: absolute` and give it `left` and `top` coordinates relative to the button, like this:

```
$("#but button").click(function(){
  var pos = $(this).offset(),
      div = $("#mydiv");

  // Make it visible off-page so
  // we can measure it
  div.css({
    "display": "block",
    "border": "1px solid black",
    "position": "absolute",
    "left": -10000,
    "top": 0
  });

  // Move it where we want it to be
  div.css({
    "left": pos.left + 10,
    "top":  pos.top - div.height() - 10
  });
});
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/ilowij/5) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/ilowij/5/edit)

---

**Original answer**:

The most obvious thing would be to change the markup so the div is in the right place to start with.

It's hard to tell what you're asking, but if you want to move `#mydiv` above `#but`:

```
$("#but button").click(function(){
    $("#mydiv").css("display","block").insertBefore("#but");
});
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/ilowij/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/ilowij/1/edit)

But if you want to put it before the *button* but inside `#but`:

```
$("#but button").click(function(){
    $("#mydiv").css("display","block").insertBefore(this);
});
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/ilowij/2) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/ilowij/2/edit)

Comment: Thank you for reply, I want to make as a tooltip, I think I need to make div with absolute ?

Comment: @user1139767: That's the usual way, yes. That would be an entirely different question.

Comment: Yeah sorry for stupid question. So how is it possible to make with absolute?

Comment: I have one more question, I want to close this "mydiv" div with click on outside this div ? the code I am using is not working properly: $('#mydiv').click(function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
        });
      
        $(document).click(function() {
            $('#mydiv').fadeOut(300);
        });

Comment: @user1139767: That's a different question, I recommend posting it separately.

Comment: Ok i will post different ;)